# Can I use Mui Components without Mui theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I have a project where I define my own Theme with `@emotion/styled`. I was wondering if I can use one of the Mui components but without defining Theme from Mui with `createTheme`. I would like to use `Data-Grid` from Mui or `Material-React-Table`. When I tried to use it directly in my project, I was receiving an error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mode')
    at getBorderColor (GridRootStyles.js:8:1)
    at GridRootStyles.js:158:1
    at processStyleArg (createStyled.js:66:1)
    at createStyled.js:172:1
    at handleInterpolation (emotion-serialize.browser.esm.js:139:1)
    at serializeStyles (emotion-serialize.browser.esm.js:264:1)
    at emotion-styled-base.browser.esm.js:123:39
    at emotion-element-c39617d8.browser.esm.js:38:1
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef
```